# SlickGrid not displaying SQL data in an MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, slickgrid

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344293/how-to-load-json-data-into-slickgrid-with-razor-mvc-4) on StackOverflow describes an issue where data from SQL is not displaying in SlickGrid in an MVC application. I am having the same issue. When I navigate to www.example.com/aqi/Products/Index, the SlickGrid displays, but the data from article_creator column in SQL does not appear.

[image]

The Web Inspector Network tab displays the data in the article_creator column from SQL that should appear in the SlickGrid. In this example, the text "Test" should appear in the SlickGrid.

[image]

In the other post, the solution was to check the Web Inspector console for errors. My browsers Web Inspector console has no errors, so I am unsure what to do next.

[image]

**Controllers/AppController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using aqi.Models;

namespace aqi.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Products.ToList());
        }

        public JsonResult GetSlickGridData()
        {
            var slickGridData = db.Products.ToList();
            var jsonResult = Json(slickGridData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return jsonResult;
        }
    }
}
```

**Scripts/SlickGridProducts.js**

```
var grid;
var columns = [
    { id: "article_creator", name: "article_creator", field: "article_creator", width: 100 }
];
var options = {
    editable: true,
    enableAddRow: true,
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    asyncEditorLoading: false,
    autoEdit: false
};

$(function () {
    var slickdata = [];
    $.getJSON("/aqi/Products/GetSlickGridData", function (items) {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            slickdata[i] = {
                article_creator: items[i].article_creator
            };
        }
    });

    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", slickdata, columns, options);
})
```

**View/Products/Index.cshtml**

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/slick.grid.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/slick.core.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/slick.grid.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/SlickGridProducts.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="myGrid"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the grid initialization inside `$.getJSON` callback since it is asynchronous. e.g.

```
$(function () {
    var slickdata = [];
    $.getJSON("/aqi/Products/GetSlickGridData", function (items) {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            slickdata[i] = {
                article_creator: items[i].article_creator
            };
        }
       grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", slickdata, columns, options);
    });
})
```

Or, if you want to show the grid beforehand with no data and refresh it later after pulling data, then.

```
$(function () {
    var slickdata = [];
    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", slickdata, columns, options);

    $.getJSON("/aqi/Products/GetSlickGridData", function (items) {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            slickdata[i] = {
                article_creator: items[i].article_creator
            };
        }
        //set the new data here and invalidate the grid
        grid.setData(slickdata);
        grid.invalidate();
    });
})
```

Note: I just noticed that you have 2 empty rows from the image. Which i believe 1 from a valid array item and the other for the new row since you set `enableAddRow:true`. This will only occur if you have typos on column `field` property` or incorrect dataset.

Comment: Thank you very much @winghei. Your solution worked perfectly, and the data is now appearing in SlickGrid. I appreciate the help.